# meteor HTTP "GET" call

Tags: javascript, get, meteor

ok so im trying to call a certain file called "map.html"

```
HTTP.call("GET",
 "/client/map.html",
          {},
          function (error, result) {
            if (result.statusCode === 200) {
              $("body").html(result.content);
            }
          });
```

the file code is:

```
<template name="map">
    <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 1000px; height: 1000px;"></div>
</template>
```

if i take out the template tag the app wont start "client/map.html:1: bad formatting in HTML template"

but that adding template tag does not working either my result.content gives back an empty body tag, i think im lacking a big part of the meteor http calls.

see response below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/packages/accounts-facebook/facebook_login_button.css?7b6e74d628e59311774e7b3409bdc3686e70e788">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/packages/accounts-github/github_login_button.css?4b6d8c2193c93dddce919620b231b5a94e6a9faf">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/packages/accounts-twitter/twitter_login_button.css?b0667609964694bc045cfee5961cf78e761f82a5">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/packages/accounts-google/google_login_button.css?6636e1d8ac79bff54828e78df6e3d407e6b6c38e">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/packages/accounts-meetup/meetup_login_button.css?ea299301e151180110c73c0dad415573cdcc7d67">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/packages/accounts-ui/login_buttons.less.css?a6791c6bbc0dbffe1967f7603ad5e71a937da2f7">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/packages/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css?e5976308949024b827360231c67b6f50ee1cf8c5">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/packages/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.css?b66c9c5bfb9556bf343298e3fe6e49c39db8c222">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/packages/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-override.css?15fa5b55da5c16ed92ffe0c85c0d6aa0867b9c7f">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/client/stylesheets/ie.css?55d03cbe8dc4482082815585822d80503557fdcb">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/client/stylesheets/print.css?5d4514803362274f0bd875bc5a9ba81d6e49dbb0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/client/stylesheets/screen.css?02fad6adf7c3c0e3b20a75fc5ab594cb1343f993">


<script type="text/javascript">
__meteor_runtime_config__ = {"meteorRelease":"0.6.5.1","ROOT_URL":"http://localhost:3000/","ROOT_URL_PATH_PREFIX":"","serverId":"NDg93Twm6549DtLMW"};
</script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/underscore.js?a1286cdb983623d4d035c8d7cd7a1e8e15274cf5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meteor.js?701b92c6c05538cfff59c73f747498bf49ff73b1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/standard-app-packages.js?be7072e6abfda638502b63fa0f809c85c8c2b8ed"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/random.js?a592658942f32ab31e84c4e67768f13f07a8e4b4"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/jquery.js?1a9d113f1f0c905a877e6eb3d97b07a871baa416"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/domutils.js?c5d4d4c5629038d1bb6deea7acd7a0512d406fe3"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/liverange.js?b3097d72d458e645fd4f0021c8ff5189abe8d98a"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/universal-events.js?5bfa39513d2caa4af4f829d7f4907afae3601adf"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ordered-dict.js?bf8af2f26c8d96bf8b2e6b407d3ed69f23c2cd37"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/deps.js?5ac28feec1f3e0539889ecde598dd9d01e408b41"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/json.js?e22856eae714c681199eabc5c0710b904b125554"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/ejson.js?6798aba30085d088a96e75a363ca1a100b990bfd"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/minimongo.js?e21b5896248d8b375979901f4f3d4907fd4cb99e"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/spark.js?3a050592ceb34d6c585c70f1df11e353610be0ab"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/preserve-inputs.js?7b3b8bf0669f1f110126607ecd8488f719344f09"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/localstorage.js?66e8e87ffe90dfe2f3f14d2f450a49ac7a33c5b8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/logging.js?e3df5be1604658260b4000a031f1a7b969cb6133"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/check.js?a54cf3c7b3abe9208d064621eb80a3ecaf2f4add"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/reload.js?acb1a2a618bdea7a55ce912cfcf348b9d89e0876"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/livedata.js?a3d111217f95d5af907302198a85413d1acbaf05"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/insecure.js?3dc9d4a2dad55999b5b15a447d57f3d5fb66b290"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/mongo-livedata.js?a3509c5f9f4ed6ded19eaac97c69c2a91d81df81"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/service-configuration.js?65f9d7f8c45ecc9be55a58180bf579558581a9dc"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/handlebars.js?c2b75d49875b4cfcc7544447aad117fd81fccf3b"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/accounts-base.js?e991c6fc17941a584b1daa1eef54fc838068754e"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/accounts-oauth.js?ec0c258ab408470b49f37de355c3b9b55fb044e4"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/oauth.js?4aa2e1486aef79113cba73c17e8cad0e9f8d929d"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/oauth2.js?228fb002a50ab94e17475623f0e34cd441d691ba"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/templating.js?1003705ccf6a397e8fabce961be55b50108d109e"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/facebook.js?d13866aba09795d6480224d2f506e89b4e7c179d"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/accounts-facebook.js?9e890f917b8ec3c3ea39544407a7e982dbc6d5ae"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/github.js?82beb1c17f04292f0007ab4c0a271e837424d8e6"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/accounts-github.js?cd8e0996c426b07b63ab8131432e3cbb1bf3f6b9"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/http.js?4aec4250e79a92408f1c5e234a52434907239586"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/oauth1.js?471ab5c3f6f6f4fca945199077d8319ed535bb3c"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/twitter.js?466fe5521ac996774043cc558d751833e3c0fbb3"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/accounts-twitter.js?a1c5862c55c6bf951b845bee147062ac1d5fb3d4"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/google.js?af3f209a9f621263be5c2ab68480825d47a142f6"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/accounts-google.js?9ef9953d728cd324cfd7280e7b31c1b89ce5eed5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/email.js?911578310472ff10dca16a5306b7f455801d0f35"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/meetup.js?27dd52a68bc2488380c4f3cebbc1448b2914524a"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/accounts-meetup.js?e29b2fa08714acff3636e67fc28938f2a5bc0219"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/srp.js?b67965acbe0e0f66edcf4df1e5d061dadedd4216"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/accounts-password.js?7194b16ddb1435bc72cb2308aab74d326cf082ff"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/reactive-dict.js?22667928acc72f619ce81e7ac1e35def1ba9e0ae"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/session.js?5bcd2d86431dc10d5f4be0910cb6567342e1aaf6"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled.js?7ca43f42462f1bda8a5c7991bfc1e9e842828ca0"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/less.js?7d1bf981a25a449d6270558bcfc983313c40cd26"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/accounts-ui.js?1ff79db616cce9b320fe8aed6103eded31248467"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/backbone.js?9e9aaec07c5a6cc1d46dfab6736beedcd71259dd"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/bootstrap.js?86f8f0d5d5a274fd05c4a35c7a7dddb771ce2a0e"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/autopublish.js?c3059a78bb200b171099fc4fa1a9345101790ddb"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/iron-router.js?2f848a70f81fa257705f5ffa213d4eb31759e02d"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/webapp.js?5c7d940d9baab5b893f7e5904e7258ef69e7ef8b"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/packages/global-imports.js?390198a974d86e88eddf36f797eba0d2aaade01b"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/client/template.map.js?3d91a27fae0def5953c035959799cf274961ab39"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/client/template.meetme.js?ddf3af8adada307ad03aab720c4b185bb6b64e44"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/client/fb.js?2a3453bba5b8f7e5a39caf4f0fb6016f1b588104"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/client/map.js?298fd731353fe8a877a6db486a1c4691ce75a412"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/client/meetmeClient.js?67fc7d1913fdc057997e14b359de6937b9da684c"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/meetme.js?7761ad0a01c156c23e392a90dda0efd3cf938eed"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/router.js?d7e47615c35b162cbbd2c1d5d16bb82aef52149e"></script>


<title>meetme</title>
    <script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `GET` call on `/client/map.html`, you do the same thing a browser does when it enters the `/client/map.html` path on your app. So the result is the same the browser gets - the whole HTML page rendered. So the result you've pasted is correct.

What are you trying to achieve here?

If you're trying to change the path your app is in and display template accordingly, you should probably look into a [router] or [iron-router] packages that allow just that easily. You can do the same without a package with `window.location` methods and clever template helpers, thought it would be reinventing the wheel in most cases. You probably never want to call `GET` to your own server directly in a Meteor app.

Comment: Or if he is trying to render a template - Meteor.render : )

Comment: im only trying to add a new div - <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 1000px; height: 1000px;"></div> when the user clicks on "add marker" button, that div is is for the google maps, so the user can set a marker(pin) to some point, then i grab his marker lat and lan coordinates and store those in the database.i want to use HTTP.get cuase i dont see any reason to have it in a template and to be rendered everytime the user enter the site

Comment: There is no actual "/client/map.html" file so that is why you are seeing the default Meteor response.  Meteor compiles your html templates into javascript and sends it down as a js file.  You can see it in action here:  
<script type="text/javascript" src="/client/template.map.js?3d91a27fae0def5953c035959799cf274961ab39"></script>
  
So your HTTP GET call is not necessary.  Just render the template on-demand as @thinklinux suggested.  See here for more details:
http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_render

Comment: there is one thing that i dont get, if i got an html file called map, how do i force meteor to not load this file when meteor startup. i want this file to be render and loaded only when a user clicks a certain button, then the page will be loaded. because every html file within the client folder will be loaded when the app startup. but how do you deal with a file that you dont need, only if user request it

Comment: All js / html files are **loaded** on the beginning. This doesn't mean that all html files are **rendered** (displayed). You can render it in the event handler, and methods for this are countless. The easiest one is to use some kind of router. You can also render the template yourself with `Template.name()` and insert it with jQuery. Or just have it as a subtemplate surrounded with `{{#if someHelper}}`, so that it's not visible by default, and change `someHelper` result to `true` when user clicks the button.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying send request from client to another server? That's not possible in most cases. If you need get data from remote server and add it to your template you should make that at server side and wire down html to client and append html data to you template like this

```
//client
Template.map.rendered = function(){
  Meteor.call('get_remote_html_data', function(err, res){
             if(res){$('your_selector').html(res)}
  });    
}

//server
Meteor.methods{get_remote_html_data: function(){return http.get(your_remote_url)}}
```