# How to save an element in a collection with data fetched from a webservice api

Tags: meteor

A user saves a trip (from a city to another one) and before storing it into the mongo collection, my app have to fetch the trip distance and time from the mapquest api.

How and where would you put the HTTP.call ? Server side ? Client side ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251181/meteor-http-get-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install http module:

   meteor add http
2. Create a server method to call web service.  Here is my example where the user put URL and the code returns title of page.

Server code:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup

    Meteor.methods({
      getTitle: function(url) {
        var response = Meteor.http.call("GET", url);
        return response;
      }
    });
```

And here is a client code:

```
Template.new_bookmark.events({

    // add new bookmark
    'keyup #add-bookmark' : function(e,t) {      
      if(e.which === 13)
      {
        var url = String(e.target.value || "");

        if(url) {
          Meteor.call("getTitle", url, function(err, response) {
            var url_title = response.content.match(/<title[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/title>/)[1];
            var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
            bookmarks.insert({Name:url_title,URL:url,tags:["empty"], Timestamp: timestamp});
          });
        }
      }
    }
});
```

If the user press "enter" in the #add-bookmark field, I get fields value and pass it to server method.  The sever method returns page HTML source and I parse it on client, get title and store it on my collection.

Comment: Thanks, I've something like this working right now. But now I'd like something more secure. In your example would there be a way to do
bookmarks.insert({URL:url,tags:["empty"]})
And to let the server do the job for the Name and the Timestamp ?